# Not able to use FTP account created with pure ftpd

Tags: centos, virtualization, ftp

I made the new user using this command:

```
pure-pw useradd droa -u 52007 -g 52009 -d /home/droa/public_html
```

But when I connect using FTP, it says "Login authentication failed". Which other setting do I need to use?

I also have cpanel where I used to create accounts. I even checked the `/etc/pureftpd.passwd` file as well, but it only had one user which I created. I don't know which FTP cpanel uses.

The documentation of pureftp says that I need to compile with `--with-everything`.
Is there any way to do that without re-compiling?

Comment: What is the exact error message? What do the logs say?

Comment: it says login authentication failed

Answer (score 0):

pure-pw only adds the user to your `pureftpd.passwd` file. either use the `-m` option or `pure-pwconvert` to transfer the userdata into your `pureftpd.pdb` file (or equivalent for your distribution).